# How long does it take Lycium chinense to grow fruit (from seed)?

Tags: lycium

How many years does it take [Lycium chinense](http://www.rareseeds.com/goji-berry-lycium-chinensis/) to grow fruit, when grown from seed? Lycium chinense is one of the species of Goji Berries.

I live in southwestern Idaho (the hardiness zone ranges between about 4a and 6b, depending on the year, but usually -10 to -15° F. is the coldest it gets). It gets very hot (the hottest it's gotten has been about 116° F., but usually between about 100–110° F. is the yearly high), dry and semi-arid in the summer, and is often wet in the spring/winter and late fall. Our soil is clay-loam.

Note that the link refers to it as Lycium chinensis, but I've verified that this is indeed Lycium chinense. The Goji plants there are Lycium barbarum, though. Goji are in the Solanaceae family (along with peppers and tomatoes), but they're perennial shrubs.

Comment: Within 4 years in good conditions but - why not start from plants?

Comment: Do you know anywhere where you can get plants for Lycium chinense? There are a number of places where you can get Lycium barbarum as a plant, but I don't know of any for Lycium chinense.

Comment: The lack of plants for sale and the fact seeds can be found seems to indicate a possibility that Lycium chinense might take less time to fruit than Lycium barbarum.

Comment: I knew of a place, but they don't have it in stock atm

Answer (score 1):

https://www.restorationseeds.com/products/goji-berry says 4-5 years to reach maturity. But not all bushes grown from seed produce fruit so it's recommended you start with a bush.

Comment: That link is for Lycium barbarum, which although good to know, is a different species of Goji.

Comment: I'm just saying, if it's a different species, the times might be different. Thanks for the answer.